# Explain equation to calculate CDS spread

Tags: cds

I've come across this equation in a text and can't figure out what part of it is doing.

(Using quarterly installments)

$\frac{1}{4*10^4}s^t \sum\limits_{u=1}^{4t} p_{0.25u}[(1-\pi_{0.25u}) + \frac{1}{2}(\pi_{0.25u-1} - \pi_{0.25u})] = (1-R) \sum\limits_{u=1}^{4t} p_{0.25u}(\pi_{0.25u-1} - \pi_{0.25u})$

Where $p_{0.25u}$ is the price of a risk free zero coupon bond maturing at time $t$.

Why are we dividing the left hand side by $4*10^4$?

Comment: Can you cite the source of the equation please?

Comment: @KyleBalkissoon it comes from Malz - Financial Risk Management Models, History and Institutions. ps: I corrected a typo in the equation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $10^4$ factor is to calculate the answer in [bps (basis points).](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basis_point) 
It looks like $4$ is the denominator for the summation of the quarterly installments.

Comment: Oh I didn't catch that re the bps. Making it quarterly is bc the spread is annual them?

Comment: The CDS spread is bps/year in Malz.

Comment: If it's already in bps/year, why do we need the 10^4 factor?

Comment: Because 1-R is not in bps.